# "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host" I am trying to connect my Eclipse project to Dbeaver

Tags: java, postgresql, database-connection

When I try to connect to my database I get a connection error with the following stacktrace

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.work.utils.DAOUtility.getConnection(DAOUtility.java:51)
    at com.work.daos.CustomerDAOImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDAOImpl.java:21)
    at com.work.views.View.displayWelcome(View.java:77)
    at com.work.controllers.Controller.init(Controller.java:21)
    at com.work.Driver.main(Driver.java:8)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:238)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my code

```
package com.work.utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class DAOUtility {
    private static String CONNECTION_USERNAME;
    private static String CONNECTION_PASSWORD;
    private static String CONNECTION_URL;
    private static Connection connection;
    
    static {
        try {
            InputStream input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("application.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(input);
            
            String SYSTEM_VARIABLE_USERNAME = properties.getProperty("USERNAME_PROPERTY");
            String SYSTEM_VARIABLE_PASSWORD = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_PROPERTY");
            String SYSTEM_VARIABLE_URL = properties.getProperty("URL_PROPERTY");
            
            CONNECTION_USERNAME = System.getenv(SYSTEM_VARIABLE_USERNAME);
            CONNECTION_PASSWORD = System.getenv(SYSTEM_VARIABLE_PASSWORD);
            CONNECTION_URL = System.getenv(SYSTEM_VARIABLE_URL);
            
            input.close();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(CONNECTION_URL);
        
        // not necessary if it can be found in classpath
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not register driver!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
            //System.out.print(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, CONNECTION_USERNAME, CONNECTION_PASSWORD);
        }
        
        return connection;
    }
}
```

i've tried removing the "public" part from my URL but that didn't work, i've reconnected the connection in DBeaver but didn't help either. I've double checked my username, password and URL but I can't seem to figure out why it fails.

[image of database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFDHb.png)

Comment: What is the structure of your url, it seems its failing to connect to the url

Comment: What is the public part of your URL?  I was not aware URL had such components.

Comment: "*UnknownHostException*" means that your JDBC URL contains a hostname that simply doesn't exist (or can't be resolved by name)

Comment: jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/postgres is my URL @joemokenala.                                 I added the public part after postgres so the URL would be "jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/postgres/public"